# Splash screen in flutter not navigating to desired screen

Tags: flutter, dart

My splash screen is not navigating to the HomeScreen after 500 milliseonds

I maintaing two files in my application:

```
main.dart
app.dart
```

In my main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(SplashScreen());
}
```

In my splash_screen.dart:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  late Store store;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAppAndNavigate();
  }

  Future initAppAndNavigate() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(microseconds: 100);
    return Timer(_duration, navigateToHomeScreen);
  }

  void navigateToHomeScreen() {
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => App());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        // backgroundColor: CustomColors.primary,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff75c760),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _buildAppName(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            _buildSpinner(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAppName() {
    return Text(
      "My App",
      style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSpinner() {
    return SpinKitDoubleBounce(
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see I've defined the the duration to 500 milliseconds but the application just wont go to the App().

Now App() has all my routes defined. Inside the stateful widget:

```
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  Widget loadScreens(int currentIndex) {
    switch (currentIndex) {
      case 0:
        return HomeScreen();
      case 1:
        return CategoryScreen();
      case 2:
        return WishlistScreen();
      case 3:
        return ProfileScreen();

      default:
        HomeScreen();
        return Container();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: loadScreens(_currentIndex),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onTap: (value) {
            setState(
              () {
                _currentIndex = value;
              },
            );
          },
          selectedItemColor: Color(0xff75c760),
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(EvaIcons.messageCircleOutline),
              label: "Feed",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(EvaIcons.activity),
              label: "Catergory",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(EvaIcons.heartOutline),
              label: "Favorites",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(EvaIcons.personOutline),
              label: "Profile",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 4000),(){
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen()));
});
```

Comment: I get this two errors:
`Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.`

And,
`The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.`